# Simple Modal: Nested modal

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I'm using the jquery simplemodal plugin, but i'm not sure that with this plugin is possible open a simplemodal dialog from another simplemodal dialog. Ans also i just want to show first modal dialog opened with grayed out when second modal dialog is opened.

Answer (score 2):

SimpleModal does not support nested modals. Maybe some of [these](http://www.jquery4u.com/windows/14-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes/) might?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleModal does not support nested modals

Check bpopup JQuery plugin. It allows nested modal popups very very easy.

http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

Look for Example 6a in the previous url ;-)

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but If I was the question maker my answer should be a solution. He is looking for a plugin which do something.  I posted a link to a jquery plugin which does what he is asking. And I pointed directly to the examples page marking the example 6a it's was he is looking.